# Communication between OCaml and Python

Tags: python, ocaml

I would like to know the best way to send data from OCaml to Python and get response from Python back to OCaml.

One naive method I can think is as follows.

1) In OCaml, write data into a file (input.txt) on file system.

2) In OCaml, run python, which opens input.txt and reads the data and write the execution result into output.txt

3) In OCaml, open output.txt and read the result

Is there other easy ways to do this kind of task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: using file is not a good approach, since it creates more problem, then solves. Especially with synchronization. But you can use `mmap` module in python, and `Bigarray`'s `mmap` function to map the file into memory, thus creating a shared memory between two different processes. Although, it also has problems with synchronization. So I would suggest to use some stream approaches, like pipes, sockets, etc.

Comment: Have a look at amqp support in python and ocaml. It's a messaging protocol which let processes or threads communicate easily.

Comment: Other options are rpc like protocols: corba, com, zeroc. Each of these has libraries (some more mature than others) for both languages. But they might require a little more learning to get them to work.

Comment: At any rate, don't try to reinvent the wheel if this isn't your ultimate goal: prefer an "of the shelf" solution as much as possible, you'll get most problems sorted out for you (assuming it's well supported).

Comment: You can run them in the same process using [Pycaml](http://pycaml.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 8):

This is a general question on how to talk between two programs, written in different languages. Actually, the problem should be further subdivided into two separate subproblems:

1. What transport to use? (file, socket, etc)
2. How to serialize and deserialize data.

The first question is very general. You can use sockets of different kinds, pipes, shared memory, zmq library, or whatever. It is hard to give any advice here, since all choices has their cons and pros. Maybe using `http` over `TCP` socket is not a bad choice, since they're ubiquitous, and there excellent libraries on both sides of the pipe. Another approach is to use pipes, and to call one or another part using `popen` system call, that will create a process for you and return pipes that you can read or write from. As an extension of the previous, you can even use `python` as a library, and call the interpreter directly from your ocaml program, passing strings with code. Depending on your task it can be suitable or not.

The second question, is about how to serialize OCaml native type, like `int` to bytes, and then read this bytes as python native `int` type, and vice verse. There're some solutions here, not so many though. You can use `json` with `ezjsonm` library on the OCaml (on python there is a `json`), you can use `cap'n'proto` it has bindings in OCaml and Python. Also, there are well known Google Protocol buffers, aka protobufs, with several bindings in OCaml, including `piqi` library, that can also serialize into many formats.

There is another approach, you can make you OCaml program to be a dynamic library exposing interface in `C`, then create a python module, and call it directly as library. This is not very easy, because it requires to mess with build system, so I do not recommend it until you have performance requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [PyCaml](http://pycaml.sourceforge.net/). It lets you package OCaml code as a python extension (callable from Python) and vice-versa, so you can call Python code from OCAML.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is indeed to use a file. You can avoid writing to disk by using a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe); on a *nix system, put the file in `/tmp/` anyway.

A still relatively simple alternative is to use a network socket.